# Creating 3 perfectly equal pics that take up the height and width of the page

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am trying to get three pictures to take up 100% of the page equally. I have the width fixed with this basic code:

```
<style>
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
}

.inner {
width:101%;
overflow:hidden;
}

.column {
width:33.33333333%;
float:left;
}

.column img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
}

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="https://recodetech.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/early-vehicle-lores.jpg?quality=80&strip=info" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="https://recodetech.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/early-vehicle-lores.jpg?quality=80&strip=info" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="https://recodetech.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/early-vehicle-lores.jpg?quality=80&strip=info" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/xbtjzof8/

What I am trying to do is get the images to take up 100% of the height as well as the width, with it zooming in to fit. But I am having problems with that part.

EDIT: Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SySmN.jpg But with three images. Or like http://www.raysrestaurants.com/index without the side nav sections of course.

Comment: Can you post an image to illustrate what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want, you can do this by forcing the height of the image at 100% , leaving the width as it is and be sure to have an overflow-hidden on the column that contains the image, so it will do the trick.
Here the fiddle :

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lbeax6ju/2/

You were looking for that ?

Edit: and as I forgot to say, also so what thathungerstar said.

Comment: Yes, that works! Now I just have to work on my overlays and everything else. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect but it works:

```css
html, body, .container, .inner, .column, .column img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Percentage heights only work if the parent element has a height set on it. In this case we keep *"cascading"* `height: 100%` down to the image.